# User Observer still the same value

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My UserObserver works OK after creating the first user. When I create the second user, the function returns the values of the first user, why?

In UserObserver:

```
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
public function created(User $user)
    {   
        dd($user->first()->id);
    }
}
```

Everything is fine in the database. The next registration is correctly assigned the next id number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of an User and call `->first()` it will create an `QueryBuilder` and actually get the first. Just use the `$user` that is passer to the method.

```
public function created(User $user)
{   
    dd($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

A function was the problem first() = firts user in database